# Alignment of text in Java

Tags: java

I'm very new to Java and I'm taking a fundamental class for coding in Java. I'm having trouble aligning text in my program in order for the results to look more readable. My professor is very picky about every little detail including centering.

Essentially what I'm trying to do is center my output results which improves readability.

```
public static void main (String[] args)
   {
      //local constants

      //local variables
      String userPhrase, firstWord, newPhrase;
      int stringLength, indexSpace;
      char thirdChar;

      /********************   Start main method  *****************/
      //Prompts user for phrase
      System.out.print (">>Enter a phrase containg more than 1 word<<: ");
      userPhrase = Keyboard.readString();

      //Displays phrase input given by user
      System.out.print ("\n");
      System.out.println ("You entered: " + userPhrase);

      //Displays phrase length in characters
      System.out.print ("\n");
      stringLength = userPhrase.length();
      System.out.println ("The length of the phrase is: " + stringLength + " characters");

      //Displays third character in phrase
      char third_char = userPhrase.charAt(2);
      System.out.println ("The third chracter of the phrase is: " + third_char);

      //Displays index of first space
      indexSpace = userPhrase.indexOf(' ');
      System.out.println ("The index space of the phrase is: " + indexSpace);

      //Displays the first word
      firstWord = userPhrase.substring (0, indexSpace);
      System.out.println ("The first word is: " + firstWord);

      //Displays altered phrase without first word
      newPhrase = userPhrase.substring(indexSpace);
      System.out.println ("The phrase without the first term is: " + newPhrase);







   } //end main

}//end String Practice Coding
```

Comment: are you trying to center the source code, or the execution output, or both?

Comment: Just looking to center the output results.

Comment: Anyone have an idea?